# A flower-shaped robot-control puzzle

Tags: pattern, visual, strategy

[image]
The goal of this puzzle is to find a sequence of max 5 commands that will move the triangle through the maze and visit all colored squares.

Three types of commands can be used:

- F0 makes the sequence start over.
- The arrows (↑, ↱, ↰) move the triangle (forward) or make it change orientation (clockwise, anti-clockwise).
- ️s change the color of the square the triangle is in to the color of the ️. Each command can (but does not need to) have a color. A colored command is only executed if the triangle is in a square of the same color.

If you want to play around with the mechanics interactively, you can do that [here](https://turing.gausshq.com/puzzles/223.524c0a2b017efa0b37c4). (Disclaimer: I am one of the developers of the site.)

CLARIFICATIONS:

- Attempting to move out of the board is not allowed.
- The sequence terminates automatically once all squares have been
  visited.
- Grey squares are not colored squares. They considered "out of the maze".

Comment: From playing around with the interactive version, it seems that grey is not a colour, and in fact moving to a grey square is considered "moving out of the board". Is that correct?

Comment: "️s change the color of the square the triangle is in to the color of the ️. Each command can (but does not need to) have a color. A colored command is only executed if the triangle is in a square of the same color." That means ️ is a no-op.

Comment: @msh210 I think there are two separate colours associated with a ️ command. (1) _Any_ command can be coloured, meaning that it is only executed when the colour of the current square matches. (2) The ️ command, specifically, has a parameter which is a colour but needn't be the same as the colour of the command, saying what colour to paint the square with. Think of #1 as the colour of a box the command is in (the box is only opened when the colour matches where you are) and #2 as a part of the command itself.

Comment: FWIW I am red-green colour blind (pretty common) and find the magenta(?) and blue(?) very hard to distinguish.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Sorry about that. I didn't think about it. I will write it down and fix it as soon as I have the time. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've solved it! Enter my commands on the [interactive puzzle](https://turing.gausshq.com/puzzles/223.524c0a2b017efa0b37c4) to see it play through, or watch this heavily compressed .gif I made.

> [image]

Some commentary on how I worked through it (probably not that insightful):

> I spent maybe an hour running into walls and messing with the painting commands. So I decided I would at least try to make him do a simple circle, so I went with up, left, up. Then my next thought was just to escape out of that sequence, so I tried turning purple right, and boom, it worked.

And some suggestions for improving the app:

> I think the most helpful things you could add here is a "step" button, that allows you to run the program step by step, and a pause/play button that allows you to pause execution. I also found it surprising that when I first ran my solution, upon completion, I was immediately taken to the homepage. I was really stressed for a moment as I went back to remember my answer.

Comment: Well done! I see what you mean. "Debugging" solutions should be easier.
Sorry about redirecting you to the homepage. I just put the minimal necessary things together to make the puzzle playable without solving the ones that precede it.
Thank you for the feedback!